# Docusign in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, docusignapi

I'm trying to implement Document signing on my rails app.
I have a template which is sent to many users.

So i have made a custom tag with label `Member` and i want to fill it with a custom text say 'abc' through my app.

Here is my code which i tried so far. The member part still looks blank. Other fields like name, signature and date are working properly.

```
client = DocusignRest::Client.new
@envelope_response = client.create_envelope_from_template(
            status: 'sent',
            email: {
              subject: "The test email subject envelope 7",
              body: "Envelope body content here"
            },
            template_id: template_id,
            signers: [
               {
                 name: 'Name',
                 email: 'sample_email@gmail.com',
                 role_name: 'Expert',
                 tabs: {
                    text_tabs: [
                      { 
                        tab_label: 'Member', 
                        value: 'abc'
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            )
```

I dont know where i went wrong. Please help

Comment: Where is `client` coming from? Which libraries are you using for implementing document signing?

Comment: Please post the corresponding JSON that this creates and sends out (you should be able to print it right before sending).  The first thing I notice is that it should be `tabLabel` not `tab_label` for the name of the property, but there could be other issues as well.

Comment: @Ergin sry for the late reply.. how can i puts the json response..

Comment: You need to capture the JSON your code is sending out, probably through an external tool.  Lots of people find [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) easy to use and it's free.  Once we see the JSON you're sending out I think the problem will be obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems the 'text_tabs' should not be embedded inside a 'tabs'. instead, pass the 'text_tabs' directly within a signer.  also, instead of 'tab_label', try just using 'label'.

Comment: it may be the case that you also need to pass document_id (set it to 1, for instance) along with label, value and possibly name.

Comment: Yea the problem was i made a number tab in envelope instead of text tab

Comment: subsequent to answering this question, the documentation in the README was fixed so that the extra tabs is not there: https://github.com/jondkinney/docusign_rest/commit/332073e44a00e4f360f6124b86e798ac894c7502